# Switching back to an older version having high period of security and maintenance

Tags: 15.10, security, maintenance

I am presently using ubuntu 15.10. Just want to know if I can switch back to an older version which has more security and maintenance as 15.10 has only a 9 month one.

Comment: The easiest way to go back a version is to make sure you have good backups of all your data, install the version you want and then restore your data from the back up.  But as pointed out in answer below Version 16.04 is an LTS release and that's due out on April 21.  I'd wait for that then stay with LTS only releases from then on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both yes and no. It's not about the old software, but internals will also change and may result to a heavily broken system. It's advisable to wait for another month and upgrade to 16.04 LTS and enjoy 5 year of support.